# "pointer being freed was not allocated" while creating an array of template instantiations in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, dynamic-arrays, rule-of-three

I will simplify the problem in order to present a minimal and reproducible example:

I have a class `Polynomial` which is just a wrapper around an array of coefficients. For convenience in my analyses downstream it is a good idea to write it as a template regarding to the max. degree it can represent. Please remember that an `N`-th degree polynomial will hold `N+1` coefficients.

```
template <const unsigned int MaxDeg>
class Polynomial {

  public:

    int *coefficients;

    Polynomial(int* arr) {
        coefficients = new int[MaxDeg+1];
        for (unsigned int i=0; i <= MaxDeg; i++) coefficients[i] = arr[i];
    }

    Polynomial() {
        coefficients = new int[MaxDeg+1]();
    }

    ~Polynomial() {
        delete[] coefficients;
    }

    int& operator[](int index) const {
        return coefficients[index];  
    }
};
```

In my `main` I test the code with creating one polynomial and then a one-sized array for it:

```
    int f_q[] = {5, 9, 6, 16, 4, 15, 16, 22, 20, 18, 30};
    Polynomial<10> P_f_q(f_q);
    Polynomial<10> P_arr[1] = {P_f_q}; // this line raises error
```

I get the following memory error:

```
test(33770,0x10de6be00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fef43605420: pointer being freed was not allocated
test(33770,0x10de6be00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    33770 abort      ./test
```

In reality my code is much more complex but I commented out as much as I could and I really can't see where does the error come from(?)

Comment: You need to provide a copy constructor (and copy assignment operator). The compiler created one is not good when you are doing manual memory management.

Comment: Specifically, the default copy constructor results in two objects sharing coefficients, and thus a double deletion.

Comment: Ah, OK. But where is a copy constructor called here? `Polynomial<10> P_arr[1] = {P_f_q};`

Comment: @maciek, Probably, here is where the copy constructor is called in your code "Polynomial<10> P_f_q(f_q);"

Comment: How do you expect something from `p_f_q` to wind up in a completely different object without copying it, at some point along the way?

Comment: @maciek, The first thing is that you need to define a copy constructor. The second thing is that you should also define (overload) a copy assignment operator=.  Here is where you use the copy assignment in your code "Polynomial<10> P_arr[1] = {P_f_q};" (But, it seems you have not defined the copy assignment either.)

Comment: This is why on your previous question I suggested making `coefficients` a `std::vector<int>` instead of an `int*`. Although if you're going to template on `MaxDeg` thus you always know the size of the container you're allocating at compile time, you could use a `std::array<int, MaxDeg>`.

Comment: @maciek `int main() { int a[] = {1}; Polynomial p1(a); Polynomial p2 = p1; }` -- If this simple program can cause all havoc, it's time to investigate your `Polynomial` class and write it so that *all* copy situations are working correctly before using `Polynomial` any further.